# Storing Contacts in Firebase Database for Backend Systems

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I want to use Firebase Database to store contact form submissions from a single page website. That data will integrate with backend technologies that may eventually require authentication but this form is a simple contact request.

I'm running a gulp/webpack setup with the module below to submit the form data. Once I store the data I plan to use the sample Firebase Function with Nodemailer to send the contact's details by email to a gmail account.

So far I have been unable to intake the form though! Am I doing something wrong? I've successfully done this before with React so I'm a little confused how my Babel/ES6 setup isn't working. (FYI I call this function in the main JS file)

Any help is appreciated! Take a look below:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
try {
   var config = {
    apiKey: "<HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>",
    authDomain: "<HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>",
    databaseURL: "<HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>",
    projectId: "<HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>",
    storageBucket: "<HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>",
    messagingSenderId: "<HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
} catch (e) {

}

function ContactForm() {
// Shortcuts to DOM Elements.
this.contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
this.contactName = document.getElementById('contact-name');
this.contactEmail = document.getElementById('contact-email');
this.contactPhone = document.getElementById('contact-phone');
this.contactZipcode = document.getElementById('contact-zipcode');
this.contactMessage = document.getElementById('contact-message');
this.contactSubmit = document.getElementById('contact-submit');
}

/**
 * Saves a new contact to the Firebase DB.
 */

ContactForm.prototype.ContactSubmit = function(name, email, phone, zipcode, 
message) {
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('contacts');
  firebaseRef.child("contact").set({
    name,
    email,
    phone,
    zipcode,
    message
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('stored to firebase');
  }, (e) => {
    console.log('failed to store to firebase');
  });

  var contactRef = firebaseRef.child().push(contact);
  return contactRef;
}

  // Saves message on form submit.
ContactForm.prototype.onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var name = contactName.value;
    var email = contactEmail.value;
    var phone = contactPhone.value;
    var zipcode = contactZipcode.value;
    var message = contactMessage.value;
    if (name && email && phone && zipcode && message) {
      return ContactSubmit(name, email, phone, zipcode, 
message).then(function() {
        contactSubmit.click();
      });
      contactName.value = '';
      contactEmail.value = '';
      contactPhone.value = '';
      contactZipcode.value = '';
      contactMessage.value = '';
    }
  };

 export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have no reference to a child on this line:

```
var contactRef = firebaseRef.child().push(contact);
```

In addition to that, there is no variable (that I can see...) that's called `contact` so this (`.push(contact)`) won't work. Also, your users are saving their contact data in one object property ('contact' child in 'contacts' object). As shown below:

```
firebaseRef.child("contact").set({ ... });
// You need to distinguish them by either using the user's uid or using the push()
```

What you want to do is have a method of distinguishing the different user contact info (As mentioned in the above code's comment. I choose to use the latter). Example:

```
var contactRef = firebaseRef.push({ ... }, error => { /* Do stuff when done */ })
```

in `ContactForm.prototype.onsubmit` you call `ContactSubmit` without `this` keyword. And in the same function invocation, you forget to use `this` again here:

```
.then(function() {
    contactSubmit.click();
  })
```

Now that I've looked at your code again, I noticed that you also forgot to use `this`

```
// here
var name = contactName.value;
// ... till here...
var message = contactMessage.value;
```

I don't know why but what you are doing feels like overkill. Give me a sec to try and code up something quick.

```js
/**
 * Saves a new contact to the Firebase DB.
 */

// When the contactForm's been submitted, stop it from doing the normal thing of redirecting and do all this stuff below
contactForm.addEventlistener('submit', function(_eve) {
  _eve.preventDefault();

  // Get references to DOM Elements
  var name = document.getElementById('contact-name'),
    email = document.getElementById('contact-email'),
    phone = document.getElementById('contact-phone'),
    zipcode = document.getElementById('contact-zipcode'),
    message = document.getElementById('contact-message');

  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('contacts');
  firebaseRef.push({
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      zipcode,
      message,
      id: uuid.v4() // or uuid() if you used the gist, or uuid.v1() if you are using the time based uuid generator.
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('stored to firebase');
      name.value = '';
      email.value = '';
      phone.value = '';
      zipcode.value = '';
      message.value = '';
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('Error:', e);
    });
}, false);
```

There. This should work. When the user submits the form we stop it in it's tracks, take the values you need, push into Firebase, and voila! You're done.

By the way, you probably want a property saved in Firebase that will help you identify the user, whether by uid or whatever method you choose.

Comment: You are amazing Kitanga. How do I get a uid from Firebase without them having any authentication?

Comment: Anytime @JoeGrotto :D. Honestly, I think it's best you just ignore that last part, I don't see much of use for it. But I also think that a uid will be useful later on, with that said [use this library to create UUIDs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#quickstart---pre-packaged-for-browsers-not-recommended). You could also try using ChanceJS' guid(). There's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jcxplorer/823878) with uuid version4 compliant JS implementation.

Comment: Check the above snippet, I'm changing it to reflect the above discussion.